# Should we merge [tag:sars-cov-2] and [tag:covid-19] or do we want to have two tags distinguishing the virus from the disease?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Should we merge [sars-cov-2](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sars-cov-2) and  [covid-19](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19) or do we want to have two tags distinguishing the virus from the disease?

Answer (score 3):

They're different things so separate tags are appropriate. What's needed is decent descriptions so people will understand that they're different.

Comment: Shameless plug: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21201/who-came-up-with-the-sars-cov-2-name